# Implementing publicRuntimeConfig analog for nextjs version 13 to inject API endpoint in both backend and frontend

Tags: next.js, apollo-client, next.js13

I'm looking for a way to inject runtimeConfiguration available both on client and server (graphql API endpoint for Apollo). I have a nextjs 13 app with Apollo Provider

src/app/layout.tsx

```js
import type {Metadata} from "next";
import {Rubik} from "next/font/google";
import {Providers} from "./providers";
import {ApolloWrapper} from "@/lib/apolloWrapper";

const rubik = Rubik({subsets: ["latin"]});

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Lifefication",
  description: "Application to track habits and goals",
};

export default function RootLayout({children}: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
    <body className={rubik.className}>
    <ApolloWrapper>
      <Providers>
        {children}
      </Providers>
    </ApolloWrapper>
    </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

ApolloWrapper is defined (src/lib/apolloWrapper.tsx):

```js
"use client";

import { ApolloLink, HttpLink } from "@apollo/client";
import {
  NextSSRApolloClient,
  ApolloNextAppProvider,
  NextSSRInMemoryCache,
  SSRMultipartLink,
} from "@apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support/ssr";

const GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT || "http://example.com/not-defined";

function makeClient() {
  const httpLink = new HttpLink({uri: GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT});

  return new NextSSRApolloClient({
    cache: new NextSSRInMemoryCache(),
    link:
      typeof window === "undefined"
        ? ApolloLink.from([
          new SSRMultipartLink({
            stripDefer: true,
          }),
          httpLink,
        ])
        : httpLink,
  });
}

export function ApolloWrapper({ children }: React.PropsWithChildren) {
  return (
    <ApolloNextAppProvider makeClient={makeClient}>
      {children}
    </ApolloNextAppProvider>
  );
}
```

I found several options:

1. Prefix env var with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` (https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#bundling-environment-variables-for-the-browser), but then I will have to provide in build time and it will be "inlined" in the package, so I will have to build a separate package & docker image for each environment which is against 12 factor and frankly is inconvinient.
2. Use publicRuntimeConfig (https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/runtime-configuration), but in the documentation it says that this feature is considered "legacy" and to be honest I can't fgure out how to use it within new app router
3. There some other suggestions I found online like serve configuration via internal(nextjs) API which I find excessive for the usecase.

Is there a better way which fits all three requirements:

- is dynamic (so can be changed via env vars for different environments but within the same build artifact).
- is not deprecated or considered "legacy"
- doesn't add a network overhead to read the configuration

Answer (score 0):

I was almost desperate but then I found this comment in a GitHub discussion:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/44628#discussioncomment-6918154

Which worked as a charm to me. I've created envProvider, exactly like in that discussion:

**/src/lib/envProvider.tsx**

```js
'use client'

import { createContext, useContext, ReactNode } from 'react'

export const EnvContext = createContext<Record<string, string>>({})

interface EvnProviderProps {
  children: ReactNode
  env: Record<string, string>
}

export const EnvProvider = ({ children, env }: EvnProviderProps) => {
  return <EnvContext.Provider value={env}>{children}</EnvContext.Provider>
}

export const useEnvContext = () => useContext(EnvContext)
```

In the RootLayout (**/src/app/layout.tsx**), I've added populating my env variable to it (it is a server component):

```js
import {Providers} from "./providers";
import {ApolloWrapper} from "@/lib/apolloWrapper";
import {EnvProvider} from "@/lib/envProvider";

export default function RootLayout({children}: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  const env = {
    GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT: process.env.GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT || "",
    // ...other env vars
  }

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <EnvProvider env={env}>
          <ApolloWrapper>
            <Providers>
              {children}
            </Providers>
          </ApolloWrapper>
        </EnvProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

In apolloWrapper (**/src/live/apolloWrapper.tsx**), I had to change `makeClient()` function to return not a client, but a function that returns a client so that I can inject the endpoint from the component scope:

```js
"use client";

import {ApolloClient, ApolloLink, HttpLink} from "@apollo/client";
import {
  NextSSRApolloClient,
  ApolloNextAppProvider,
  NextSSRInMemoryCache,
  SSRMultipartLink,
} from "@apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support/ssr";
import { useEnvContext } from "@/lib/envProvider";

function makeClient(endpoint: string): () => ApolloClient<any> {
  const httpLink = new HttpLink({uri: endpoint});
  return () => {
    return new NextSSRApolloClient({
      cache: new NextSSRInMemoryCache(),
      link:
        typeof window === "undefined"
          ? ApolloLink.from([
            new SSRMultipartLink({
              stripDefer: true,
            }),
            httpLink,
          ])
          : httpLink,
    });
  }
}

export function ApolloWrapper({ children }: React.PropsWithChildren) {
  const { GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT } = useEnvContext()

  return (
    <ApolloNextAppProvider makeClient={makeClient(GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT)}>
      {children}
    </ApolloNextAppProvider>
  );
}
```